# How to write a function that recursively removes instances of a character from a list?

Tags: python

I have to write a function that takes a list and char gets a list with all instances of the char removed.

I'm just not quite getting anywhere with the sublists. I've been programming in Java for some time but I'm new to python.

My code:

```
def my_remove(the_char, the_list):

    if the_list == []:#works
        return the_list

    if isinstance(the_list[0],list): #if the first element in the list is, itself, a list
        #remove the character from the first element/list and move on to other list elements in the main list
    else:
        print 'else'
        return the_list

    print 'regular return'
    return the_list
```

Comment: Do you know how to program recursive functions in Java? The structure is largely the same in Python as far as I know.

Comment: Do you have to write a recursive function?

Comment: You can implement iteration on an array as a recursive function, each time reducing the list size and terminating when no more elements are remaining.

Comment: The first thing you're going to need to do is set up the input, and decide what the output SHOULD be. If you have a test case like that, then it makes sense to look at code which has different output. Also your code doesn't actually do anything, so you have some more work to do before you have a solid question to ask.

Comment: Please don't fundamentally change the question after you have received answers. I have rolled back your edit.

Comment: Please don't make more work for others by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](//creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0), for SE to distribute the content (i.e. regardless of your future choices). By SE policy, the non-vandalized version is distributed. Thus, any vandalism will be reverted. Please see: [How does deleting work? …](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221). If permitted to delete, there's a "delete" button below the post, on the left, but it's only in browsers, not the mobile app.

Comment: You should accept one of the answers here (post one of your own and accept that if you like) and then ask a new question about your new problem. If it's related to this one, by all means link back here.

Comment: If you have a different question (in a different language...) simply [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). By changing completely a question you disrespect the people who took the bother and time to answer the original one. Look how much @user633183 put into his answer. If you change the question completely, all his work was for nothing...

Answer (score 2):

The key to this recursive problem (and most) is understanding [mathematical induction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) -

```
def my_remove(the_char, the_list):
  if the_list == []: #1
    return the_list

  elif isinstance(the_list[0],list): #2
    return my_remove(the_char, the_list[0]) \
         + my_remove(the_char, the_list[1:])

  elif the_list[0] == the_char: #3
    return my_remove(the_char, the_list[1:])

  else: #4
    return [ the_list[0] ] + my_remove(the_char, the_list[1:])

input = ['a','z',['z','b',['c','z','z']],[['d']],'z'] 

print(my_remove('z', input))
# ['a','b','c','d']
```

In the numbered comments -

1. terminating condition and base case: when the input is empty, return an empty output
2. otherwise, *by induction*, the list is *not* empty. If the first element of the list is another list, combine the result of calling `my_remove` on the first element and `my_remove` on the tail of the list, `list[1:]`
3. otherwise, *by induction*, the list is *not* empty and the first element of the list is *not* a list. If the first element matches the char, simply call `my_remove` on the tail of the list.
4. otherwise, *by induction*, the list is *not* empty and the first element is of the list is *not* a list, and the first element of the list does *not* match the char. Include the first element of the list in the output and combine it with `my_remove` called on the tail of the list

---

Your question explicitly says that helper functions cannot be used. This is most likely an indication of a bad programming teacher. Helper functions make it possible to remove complexity from your program, thereby gaining a complexity-free mind.

Given some generic functions for working on lists -

```
def isEmpty(l):
  return len(l) == 0

def isList(l):
  return isinstance(l, list)

def head(l):
  return l[0]

def tail(l):
  return l[1:]
```

We can write `my_remove` with a richer semantics that immediately communicates its intentions to the reader -

```
def my_remove(x, lst):
  if isEmpty(lst):
    return lst

  elif isList(head(lst)):
    return my_remove(x, head(lst)) \
         + my_remove(x, tail(lst))

  elif head(lst) == x:
    return my_remove(x, tail(lst))

  else:
    return [ head(lst) ] + my_remove(x, tail(lst))
```

The output is the same, of course -

```
print(my_remove('z', input))
# ['a','b','c','d']
```

---

These helpers could be further improved to protect the programmer for their misuse. Ie, raising a `RuntimeWarning` is a good way to let you know you made a mistake with your inductive reasoning -

```
def isEmpty(l):
  return isList(l) and len(l) == 0

def isList(l):
  return isinstance(l, list)

def head(l):
  if isEmpty(l):
    raise RuntimeWarning('head called on empty list')
  else:
    return l[0]

def tail(l):
  if isEmpty(l):
    raise RuntimeWarning('tail called on empty list')
  else:
    return l[1:]
```

Comment: This works except for the fact that it flattens the list. How would you go about keeping the list full of sublists?

Comment: in `elif isList(head(lst)): ...` change the `my_remove(...) + my_remove(...)` case to `[ my_remove(...) ] + my_remove(...)`

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases to handle:

1. when word is list
2. when word is str

For case 1, when word is an empty list (base case) return an empty list. 
Return the concatenated list of a list of the function invoked with the first item in the list and the result of the function invoked with the remaining items in the list.

For case 2, when the word is an empty string (base case) return an empty string, 
when the first character of the word matched the character searched for,  return the result of calling the recursive function with the rest of the string. 
Otherwise, concatenate the first character together with the result of calling the recursive function with the rest of the string.

```py
import doctest

def remove(word, char):
  """
  >>> remove([['swan'], ['elephant'], 'snake'], 'e')
  [['swan'], ['lphant'], 'snak']
  >>> remove(['swan', [['elephant']], ['snake']], 'e')
  ['swan', [['lphant']], ['snak']]
  """
  if isinstance(word, list):
    if word == []:
      return []
    head, tail = word[0], word[1:]
    return [remove(head, char)] + remove(tail, char)

  if isinstance(word, str):
    if word == '':
      return ''
    head, tail = word[0], word[1:]
    if head == char:
        return remove(tail, char)
    return head + remove(tail, char)

doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: NB this function can return `None` if any element (`word`) is neither a `list` nor a `str`